# ¿Cómo evitar la obstrucción de la salida de datos de vista previa?

Tags: jquery

Tengo desarrollo un pequeño script, donde se puede insertar formatos al texto y espacios entre otros y todas las acciones de los botones se aplica al contenedor al `div editable` donde es ahí donde se escribirá los textos/artículo.

Todo lo que escribo en el `div editable`, pasa al `textarea`, lo que me permitirá luego insertar esa información en la base de datos.

> **Nota:** El `textarea` permanecerá siempre oculto, aplicando la clase de `display none` por motivo de prácticas y desarrollo se encuentra visible, es importante recordar que es en el `div editable donde se escriben los artículos/textos etc.

Todo este proceso funciona maravillosamente desde el `div editable` hasta el `textarea`.

Ahora, el problema que presentó, es que los datos que recibo en el `textarea` no se muestra de manera automática en tiempo real en el `div` de la vista previa.

No se muestra al mismo tiempo, tengo que escribir algo en el `textarea` para mostrar los datos en la vista previa, al parecer existe una obstrucción al momento de pasar dicha información al `div` contenedor de la vista previa.

El proceso que deseo aplicar es el siguiente:
La información del `div editable` pasa al `textarea` la información que tiene el `textarea` debe pasar de la misma forma automática y en tiempo real al `div -> preview` donde es ahí donde se va visualizar como está quedando su redacción, similar a lo que sucede aquí en StackOverflow, que muestra una vista previa de lo que estás preguntando.

Este es mi código jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    let htmlDiv = $("#editor");
    htmlDiv.on("keyup", function(e) {
        $("#textarea").html(htmlDiv.html());
    });
    $("#textarea").html(htmlDiv.html());

    $('.editor-preview').keyup(function(){                  
        var value = $(this).val();
        var contentAttr = $(this).attr( 'class' );
        $( '.' + contentAttr + '' ).html(value);
    })
});
```

¿Cómo soluciono esta obstrucción que existe en la salida de datos de la vista previa del `div class="editor-preview></div>`.?

Código en ejecución:
http://jsfiddle.net/rpvthc4u/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando cambias el texto del `#editor` sólo cambia el texto del `#textarea` porque no hay ningún evento de `keyup()`.

Prodrías forzar que cuando cambias el valor en el `#editor` ejecute la función del `keyup()`.

```
$(function() {
    let htmlDiv = $("#editor");
    htmlDiv.on("keyup", function(e) {
        $(".editor-preview").val(htmlDiv.html());
        $(".editor-preview").keyup();
    });
    //$("#textarea").html(htmlDiv.html());

    $('.editor-preview').keyup(function(){                  
        var value = $(this).val();
        var contentAttr = $(this).attr( 'class' );
        $( '.' + contentAttr + '' ).html(value);
    })
});
```

Te he creado este snippet para que veas que si escribes en el `#editor`, hace que se copie el texto tanto en el `#textarea` como en el `.editor-preview`.

```js
$(function() {
    let htmlDiv = $("#editor");
    htmlDiv.on("keyup", function(e) {
        $(".editor-preview").val(htmlDiv.html());
    $(".editor-preview").keyup();
    });
    //$("#textarea").html(htmlDiv.html());

    $('.editor-preview').keyup(function(){                  
        var value = $(this).val();
        var contentAttr = $(this).attr( 'class' );
        $( '.' + contentAttr + '' ).html(value);
    })
});
```

```css
#editor {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.editor-preview {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Editable div, where the actions of the editor buttons are added -->
<div id="editor" contenteditable></div>
<!-- the textarea receives all the information of the editable div, the textarea will remain hidden, by means of display none;-->
<textarea id="textarea" class="editor-preview"></textarea>
<!-- preview of what the textarea receives -->
<div class="editor-preview"></div>
```

Comment: @lñigolrigoyenErquicia Hola, si existe el #textarea te estas olvidando del div editable donde es ahí donde se escribe el contenido, lo que se escribe ahí pasa al textarea y lo que pasa al textarea debe pasar al div de vista previa, ya le creo un bordes para que se pueda visualizar aquel div editable.

Comment: @lñigolrigoyenErquicia Ya le he creado un bordes al primer div editable, es ahí donde debes escribir, el textarea permanecerá siempre oculto por motivo de desarrollo está aún visible por las prácticas, ahora escribes ahí te darás cuenta que pasa los datos escritos al textarea, y en la vista previa no pasa a mostrar nada, pero si escribes algo en el textarea ahí sí lo muestra ese es el problema el atracamiento o obstrucción de salida de datos. Aquí tienes los cambios realizados http://jsfiddle.net/rpvthc4u/4/

Comment: @Stevin Yo creo que lo que te he puesto funciona, he añadido un snippet para que veas como funciona.

Comment: Gracias, es lo que esperaba, pensé al principio que había descartado al `textarea` pero veo que has migrado por la misma clase.

Comment: Si, con id del textarea no me dejaba. XD. Me alegro de haber te ayudado.